# Add row to start of Dgrid instead of end using Rest call

Tags: rest, dojo, dgrid

As you know, dgrid 0.4 now uses the dstore package instead of dojo's store.  Using the Rest.js in dstore, I simply want to add a new row to the dgrid using a rest call.  This works fine.  However, it adds the row at the end (as the last row) of the dgrid.  I need to add the row at the beginning (making the newly added row the first row of the dgrid).  Inside Rest.js, there is a variable called defaultNewToStart which I figured would do the trick, but even when set to true, dgrid still adds the row at the end.  Any advice on how to get Rest.js in dstore to add a row to the beginning of the dgrid.

Comment: Can you show your code, particularly how you are creating your store and grid, so we can see if there might be a commonly-overlooked mistake?

Comment: Yeah, it turns out I made a basic mistake that I bet someone would have caught.  I'm never posting another question without relevant code again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I did wrong.  In dgrid/OnDemandGrid, I set the property "sort", which was causing the queryExecutor in Trackable.js to put the newly added row at the end instead of the beginning.  So all I had to do was remove the sort property, and now it works fine.

Comment: In your defense, this is not quite as common of a mistake as I suspected, and is a good one to note for future reference, so thanks for reporting on the results.

Answer (score -1):

The add function of dstore/Memory supports `PutDirectives` as second argument other than the item you are trying to insert. `PutDirectives` has a property `beforeId` which can be used to insert the item before any existing record in store.

To add an empty row at the beginning:

```
var beforeID = null;
store.fetch().forEach(lang.hitch(this, function(data) { beforeId = data.id;}));
store.add({id: ''}, {beforeId: beforeID});
```